# Database Snapshot or Temp Table for long running import?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, wcf

The application I am working on needs to pull data from a legacy SQL system(Client) and import it into my application's SQL db (server). This methodology is implemented using WCF. I am not able to make any schema changes to the client DB. After the initial import, subsequent imports are generated based upon the clients modified and created timestamp columns. I need to pull data from 3 different tables from the client DB.

Below are the solutions i am researching currently, any feedback on pros or cons would be great. As a proof-of-concept my initial import process over WCF with net.tcp and a page size of 100 records at a time is taking .15 seconds for the WCF transaction and roughly 1.5-2.0 seconds to execute the insert SPROC on my server (trying to optimize this some more, the SPROC has to do a few checks on the server DB before the insert which i think is causing the hold up.

**Server Side Processing**
Connect to client DB primary table, then for data i require from other tables create another request to the client to provide that data. This requires the most 'round trips' from the server to the client, but requires the least amount of work on the client side since it is simply sending data.

**Temp Table**
On my server log the transaction start time, create a temp table on the client side that joins together all the tables i need, then return that result sent to the server. After the operation completes, drop the temp table on the client. Im leading this way, even though i will be sending a larger result set across the pipe, my bottleneck is the INSERT statement, and if i process it all into one larger table before sending I can do it all on the server side with 1 modified insert SPROC instead of multiple inserts.

**3rd party tool**
Use some 3rd party tool that does data diffs to do a point-in-time copy of the client tables to my server db and then process it all locally on my server DB

**MS Sync Framework**
I excluded this option, I cant make schema changes on the client tables, which it appears to require to track changes. I had a hard time understanding custom sync providers \ interfaces.

**Merge Replication**
Excluded this again due to not being able to make changes to the client.

Some of my concerns include using the tables created \ modified time stamp rows for subsequent syncs. Most of what i have read on the topic suggests this is not best practice to handle data synchronization, with the primary concern being transactions that start prior to the sync but do not complete until after the sync such that the timestamp appears to be already imported. Is there a better way to track changes?

My sync solution is really a one way sync, in that records created on the server are actually sent down to a client SPROC for insert there, then when importing we compare the PK ID coming from the client to a FK ID on the server to ensure we are not causing loops or importing duplicate records. In the event I do have a conflict, the client always wins. Again currently i'm leading towards a temptable for each import session.

Feedback?

Comment: Questions:  (A) Your test w/ 100 rows was pretty good... what's a real-life # (or range) of rows expected to be?  (B) How often will it execute?  (C) Re' **Server Side Processing**, what kind of "round trips" are you talking about?  (C1) JOINs, accessing the client as a linked server?  (C2) Not JOINs, but still one 'round trip' per row?  Or (C3) one 'round trip' per table?  If (C3), then your **Server Side Processing** design could be faster.  If (C1) or (C2), I'd try the **Temp Table** design first.  However, more detail would help, and even then, an MS MVP might have to *try* them.

Comment: (A) There are two scenarios, initial load, and subsequent syncs. Initial loading should see about 50-70k records. (B)Subsequent syncs will run every 10 minutes and should only see a few hundred records.(C) Currently i tell the client server to create a global temp table joining all of the client side tables into 1 table, i then return rows in sets of 100 back to the server for processing

Comment: Additionally, what are your thoughts on wrapping the operation in a begin\end transaction such that if the import fatally fails for whatever reason, i can just have the server not commit the transaction. Is that possible with long running transactions? Would it be better to to try\catch for each row and just log the rows that throw exceptions \ fail?

Comment: Re' (A) Is initial loading a "one-time" event, "when needing recovery" event, "daily", "weekly"...?  And have you tried an initial load (how long did it take?), or is that still in design phase?  Re' (B) No problem there, based on your testing-response time.  Re' (C) I meant to ask how round trips *WOULD* look, in your design scenario above called "**Server Side Processing**".

Comment: Re' "wrapping the operation in a begin\end transaction":  I don't think there is a technical problem with making a long-running process happen as one transaction... as long as you somehow handle the possibility of some *OTHER PROCESS UPDATING* the rows, while your update is pending.  Either (1) You know that wouldn't happen, (2) You lock to prevent it, or (3) You recheck just before committing, adjusting & integrating for their changes.